# How to set the default value of Colors in a custom control in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, winforms

I got the value to show up correctly using:

```
    [DefaultValue ( typeof ( Color ), "255, 0, 0" )]
    public Color LineColor
    {
        get { return lineColor; }
        set { lineColor = value; Invalidate ( ); }
    }
```

But after I reload the project the control is used, this value is set to White, which I can invoke Reset to get back to Red again, but I don't understand the problem.

How are you supposed to set the default value and make sure it's preserved unless I change the value manually from the default?

Actually I am also doing this, which sets Back and ForeColor to these values and the VS property editor shows them as if they are changed from the default value.

Is this wrong?

```
    public CoolGroupBox ( )
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );
        base.BackColor = Color.FromArgb ( 5, 5, 5 );
        base.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb ( 0, 0, 0 );
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[DefaultValue(...)]` attribute is a hint to designers and code generators. It is NOT an instruction to the compiler.

More info in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311339/en-us).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I used a combination of setting the value inside the constructor and the default value, and it shows up correctly now. Except for Red, it has to be Red, if it's 255, 0, 0, VS still thinks it's different than Red.

Comment: It works, but if you use 255, 0, 0, VS thinks it's different than Red. It shows up as Bold.

Comment: It is used by reflexion and iti is very useful.

Answer (score 27):

The trick is to use the Hex code of the color:

```
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0xFF0000")]
    public Color LineColor
    {
            get { return lineColor; }
            set { lineColor = value; Invalidate ( ); }
    }
```

I think you can also use "255, 0, 0" but am not sure and have normally used either the named colors or the hex code.

Comment: I've just tested, and can confirm that both RGB strings and ARGB strings are valid. Use either `"255, 0, 0"` or `"255, 255, 0, 0"` to represent red.

Answer (score 11):

What about just setting the private member variable to the default color you want?

```
private Color lineColor = Color.Red;

public Color LineColor
{
        get { return lineColor; }
        set { lineColor = value; Invalidate ( ); }
}
```

If you want it *preserved*, just take out the set accessor.

**Edit**

I see, you want the property list in the designer to show the default color.

You have to override the BackColor property of the base control, add a new DefaultValueAttribute for your *new* property, and then actually set the default color in the constructor or in the InitializeComponent() method (in the designer.cs file), which is probably better since this is for the designer.

```
public partial class RedBackgroundControl : UserControl
{
    public RedBackgroundControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]
    new public Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BackColor = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I did that the value still shows up BOLD, like I changed it from the default. I also added the DefaultValue attribute but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Also by preserved I meant initially. After that the user can set it to whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck using the `DefaultValue` attribute with properties of type `Color` or of type `Font`, but I did succeed with these methods described in the msdn documentation:

"Defining Default Values with the ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.90).aspx

I used `Color.Empty` and `null`, respectively, as the values for my private backing fields and had the public properties always return something useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set specific Attribute in the component.designer.cs in the Initializecomponent Method:

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.LineColor= System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
```

Rebuild the project and everything should also show up in the

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it worked perfectly

```
Private _BackColorSelect As Color = Color.FromArgb(214, 234, 248)

<DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "214, 234, 248")>
Public Property BackColorSelect As Color
    Get
        Return _BackColorSelect
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        _BackColorSelect = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There is quite an article about defaultvalue property initialization on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66073/DefaultValue-Attribute-Based-Approach-to-Property)

Comment: Yet it covers nothing about colors in particular.

Answer (score -2):

In DependencyProperty use a UIPropertyMetadata

like:

```
public static DependencyProperty TrueColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TrueColor", typeof (Color), typeof (LedControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));
```

Comment: The question is about winforms not wpf