# Color.Red cannot be a argument in Attribute

Tags: c#, colors, attributes

I have a cs class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DefaultValue(Color.Red)]
    public Color MyColor{get;set;}
}
```

The compiler always return error CS0182:
 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

What's wrong with me?

T_T

Comment: It's not a constant expression.

Comment: `Color.Red` is a static property accessor; it is not a constant and cannot be used as a literal; it is not, for example, an `enum`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the default value of Colors in a custom control in Winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522199/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-colors-in-a-custom-control-in-winforms)

Comment: @ta.speot.is I'm not sure if it's a duplicate. It does contain the solution to this question, but the actual question is different.

Comment: As a side note: `[DefaultValue(...)]` ***by itself*** does not actually assign a default value; it merely *declares* one; you would still need to implement the default in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted, `Color.Red` is not a constant expression. If your intent is to work with something like `PropertyGrid`, then you can achieve this by adding `ShouldSerialize*` and `Reset*` methods:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        ResetMyColor();
    }
    public Color MyColor { get; set; }

    private bool ShouldSerializeMyColor() {  return MyColor != Color.Red; }
    private void ResetMyColor() { MyColor = Color.Red; }
}
```

If your intent is to work with `XmlSerializer`, then `ShouldSerialize*` must be public (the `Reset*` is not used by `XmlSerializer`):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyColor = Color.Red;
    }
    public Color MyColor { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeMyColor() {  return MyColor != Color.Red; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
[DefaultValue ( typeof ( Color ), "255, 0, 0" )]
```

But this is not good practice: [How to set the default value of Colors in a custom control in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522199/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-colors-in-a-custom-control-in-winforms)

Comment: It may be bad practice in that specific context, but it can be perfectly fine in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Drawing.Color.Red` is not a constant expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.red%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem with attributes, where `Color` cannot be an optional constructor parameter for reasons explained here.

I have solved it by using `System.Drawing.KnownColor` instead, which is an `enum`:

```
public MyCustomAttribute(string someValue, int otherValue, KnownColor foreColor = KnownColor.Black)
{
    ...
    SomeControl.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColors(foreColor);
}
```

The only drawback is that you can only use the known colors (named colors), but these also include all the system defined colors like WindowText, ControlText, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to RGB values, you can also use a string:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]
public Color MyColor{ get; set; }
```